# White space between header and content (smart slider) on phone&tablet only Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, whitespace

I have been trying to change the code for ages, nothing seem to change on phone and tablet, white space between the header and content still appears but only on phone and tablet.

[LINK](http://icnmnaturopathy.eu/en/) to website

Answer (score 0):

If you add css code given below, then your issue will be resolved.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:767px) {
    body {
        padding-top: 0px !important;
    }
 }
```